# Does Kafka broker server take into account updates to it's configuration file?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does Kafka broker server take into account updates to it's configuration file?
Its cumbersome having to restart all the servers in the cluster simply to update a configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's currently not possible to do dynamic configuration updates.
There's a Jira ticket for that exact issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1229), and [the accompanying KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-21+-+Dynamic+Configuration) (Kafka Improvement Proposal).